# c# - SELECT statement from database with multiple records returns

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am doing a small project with asp.net. Part of the assignment is me retrieving information from an SQL Server Database. So far, I just needed single records, so I used the follow code:

```
public string getTwitterSearchHistory(string userId)
{
    if (userId != null)
    {
        List<string> history = new List<string>();
        string result = "";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT searchedTerm FROM dbo.TwitterSearchHistoryModels WHERE userId = @userId", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                result = String.Format("{0}", reader["searchedTerm"]);
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
        return result;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Now, this code works perfect when I would want retrieve a property from one record. However, now I need to retrieve a property from multiple properties. Meaning, lets say I have the following:

```
ID | UserId | searchedTerm
--------------------------------
1  | 1      | hello
2  | 1      | anothersearchedterm
3  | 1      | this is a term
```

How can I retrieve all searchedTerms for userId 1 and store them in some kind of array?

Thanks!

**EDIT: 
 I am sending an Ajax request to a method inside my controller, as such.

```
function loadHistory() {
    var detailsForGet = {
        userId: sessionStorage.getItem("userName")
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://localhost:44326/User/getTwitterSearchHistory",
        data: detailsForGet,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
}
```

Now, in the controller I have this method which executes a select query from a local DB:

```
public List<string> getTwitterSearchHistory(string userId)
{
    if (userId != null)
    {
        List<string> history = new List<string>();
        string result = "";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT searchedTerm FROM dbo.TwitterSearchHistoryModels WHERE userId = @userId", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                history.Add(String.Format("{0}", reader["searchedTerm"]));
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
        return history;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now, while debugging, I can see that the variable history holds the values good, however, in my success in thew ajax call, when I try to print the data, I get the following: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].. 
What am I doing wrong please? Thanks

Comment: `while(reader.Read())`

Comment: @Gusman Thanks :D One more question if I may... I am using this data in an AJAX call.. Meaning first I send the get request to this method and on success, I use the data, however, since it's a list, it prints System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] rather than the values..

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is out of order... If you add your code may be I will be able to help. Even better, create a new question.

Comment: @Gusman I cannot post since I just posted. Nonetheless, I edited this question. Thanks

Comment: Add the code that sends the list.

Comment: Thats all the code.. The list is the variable "history"

Comment: Be careful cause I edited the previously mentioned c# method..

Comment: Where is called from `getTwitterSearchHistory`? It's not tagged as a WebMethod or Api method so you must be calling it somewhere else.

Comment: In the ajax call, I have the url and I am using it there.

Comment: Ok I managed to fix it. I converted it to Json and passed it as such. Thanks!